# VBA If And multiple conditions

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, multiple-conditions

Could anyone help troubleshoot my coding?  The If statement requires three separate conditions = true or it checks the next if statement and loop back for the all cells the array.  There is no error so its difficult to determine the issue, plus I'm very new to VBA so there is probably a better way to accomplish this.

*Note: The cells needed in the arrays are not static hence the Find.*

```
    Sub test()
Dim i As Integer
Dim col1 As Range, col2 As Range, col3 As Range, col4 As Range, col5 As Range, col6 As Range
Dim c1arr, c2arr, c3arr, c4arr, c5arr, c6arr As Variant

Set col1 = ActiveSheet.Cells.find("Reference", , xlValues, xlWhole)
Set col2 = ActiveSheet.Cells.find("Amount", , xlValues, xlWhole)
Set col3 = ActiveSheet.Cells.find("Action", , xlValues, xlWhole)
Set col4 = ActiveSheet.Cells.find("Reference2", , xlValues, xlWhole)
Set col5 = ActiveSheet.Cells.find("Amount2", , xlValues, xlWhole)
Set col6 = ActiveSheet.Cells.find("Action2", , xlValues, xlWhole)

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, col1.Column).End(xlUp).Row

c1arr = Range(Cells(2, col1.Column), Cells(lastrow, col1.Column)).Value
c2arr = Range(Cells(2, col2.Column), Cells(lastrow, col2.Column)).Value
c3arr = Range(Cells(2, col3.Column), Cells(lastrow, col3.Column)).Value
c4arr = Range(Cells(2, col4.Column), Cells(lastrow, col4.Column)).Value
c5arr = Range(Cells(2, col5.Column), Cells(lastrow, col5.Column)).Value
c6arr = Range(Cells(2, col6.Column), Cells(lastrow, col6.Column)).Value

For i = 1 To UBound(c1arr)
    If c2arr(i, 1) > 0 And c1arr(i, 1) = c4arr(i, 1) And c2arr(i, 1) = c5arr(i, 1) Then
            c6arr(i, 1) = c3arr(i, 1)
    ElseIf c2arr(i, 1) > 0 And c1arr(i, 1) <> c4arr(i, 1) And c2arr(i, 1) <> c5arr(i, 1) Then
            c6arr(i, 1) = "Manual Review"
    End If
Next

Range(Cells(2, col6.Column), Cells(lastrow, col6.Column)).Value = c6arr
End Sub
```

[UPDATED IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/668tK.jpg)

Comment: So a little debugging is in need.  put your cursor in the For i line and hit F9.  Then run the code.  It will stop at this line.  In VBEyou can see the values of everything in the "Locals" window.  You can expand all the arrays and make sure that there is data.  If not check all your other variables to ensure they are returning the correct numbers.  Then if everything is right hit F8 to go step by step, verifying each step.  Also I do not believe you want the `Exit For` in there.  Also you know you are comparing row by row and not each value in one array against all values in the others?

Comment: You never write the contents of `c6arr` back to the worksheet. Also, In Row 1 of your data, `c2arr` is negative so will fail both tests.  Also, in your code, `c1arr` will never be equal to both `c4arr` and `c5arr` so if `c2arr` > 0 then "Manual Review" will always be the results.  As Scott writes, the `Exit For` will exit the loop if you pass the first test and stop processing the rest of the rows.  There also seem to be errors in your expected results, as you have an instance where result2 is neither "manual review" nor c3arr.

Comment: All the data returns correctly. I input the Exit For because I thought the second statement might be overwriting the first.  It looks like the issue is as you noted: row by row comparison vs each value of array against all values another.  Is that an easy fix?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld you are correct thank you!  The code is part of a larger stmt edited too much which altered the code inadvertently.  The output has returned but the issue still remains.  All values return the final if stmt rather than one returning "completed".  I removed the Exit for but the code is still broken.

Comment: @J.T. I would expect that from your code.  In NO instance in your example, is Reference = Reference2, or Amount = Amount2.

Comment: @J.T. - If you want help diagnosing a problem with the logic, perhaps describe what logic you want. As it stands, everything seems to evaluate correctly - the only thing that looks wrong is your expected results.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld The code was adjusted and sample data image updated.  15D456 150.00 does indeed match but returns incorrect result.  I do want the loop to stop if the first test is passed I placed the Exit For back into the code.  The results do not change in either way however.

Comment: @J.T. They do not match **in the same row** which is how you are doing the comparison.

Comment: You will need at least one more loop, or Find, or worksheetfunction.Match to do what you want.

Comment: @J.T. - OK, finally think your expected logic is clear. You want to search ALL of Reference for occurrences of Reference2 - where that is found,  determine if the Amount criteria is satisfied. Scott's right - you need another loop.

Comment: @J.T. - I think you want the second row to come back as "Working", not "Completed". If you want "Completed", can you explain why?

Comment: @OldUgly The image has been updated.  You have the logic correct; if E2 (Reference2) matches to A2:A5 (Reference) and F2 (Amount2) matches corresponding B2:B5 (Amount) then corresponding C2:C5 (Action) would input into G2 (Action2).  The code sample and image were poorly edited after hours of troubleshooting so that is my error.  The coding I've done so far is cobbled together from researching so I'll need more research to see how to nest loops as the simple way I know isn't working either.  I appreciate all the help in diagnosing the logic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added an extra loop and broke up the if logic in order to get the correct (?) behavior.

I get these results ...

[image]

... from this code ...

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, lastrow As Long
Dim col1 As Range, col2 As Range, col3 As Range, col4 As Range, col5 As Range, col6 As Range
Dim c1arr, c2arr, c3arr, c4arr, c5arr, c6arr As Variant

    Set col1 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("Reference", , xlValues, xlWhole)
    Set col2 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("Amount", , xlValues, xlWhole)
    Set col3 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("Action", , xlValues, xlWhole)
    Set col4 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("Reference2", , xlValues, xlWhole)
    Set col5 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("Amount2", , xlValues, xlWhole)
    Set col6 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("Action2", , xlValues, xlWhole)

    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, col1.Column).End(xlUp).Row

    c1arr = Range(Cells(2, col1.Column), Cells(lastrow, col1.Column)).Value
    c2arr = Range(Cells(2, col2.Column), Cells(lastrow, col2.Column)).Value
    c3arr = Range(Cells(2, col3.Column), Cells(lastrow, col3.Column)).Value

    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, col4.Column).End(xlUp).Row

    c4arr = Range(Cells(2, col4.Column), Cells(lastrow, col4.Column)).Value
    c5arr = Range(Cells(2, col5.Column), Cells(lastrow, col5.Column)).Value
    c6arr = Range(Cells(2, col6.Column), Cells(lastrow, col6.Column)).Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(c4arr)
        If c6arr(i, 1) = "" Then ' if already determined an answer, don't try again
            For j = 1 To UBound(c1arr)
                If c1arr(j, 1) = c4arr(i, 1) Then ' found Reference2 within Reference
                    If c2arr(j, 1) = c5arr(i, 1) And c2arr(j, 1) > 0 Then
                        c6arr(i, 1) = c3arr(j, 1)
                    Else
                        c6arr(i, 1) = "Manual Review"
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
        End If
        If c6arr(i, 1) = "" Then ' if haven't found an answer yet, it needs review
            c6arr(i, 1) = "Manual Review"
        End If
    Next i

    Range(Cells(2, col6.Column), Cells(lastrow, col6.Column)).Value = c6arr

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me, from your code and your example, when you want to see "Manual Review" in Action2.  Obviously, if References match but Amounts do not; but since that does not encompass all of the possibilities, that part of the code is a bit "sloppy".  In the code below, all instances where there is no match will be marked "Manual Review".  If that is truly the case, then the code could be made a bit cleaner (and faster).

Here's another way of doing this, using `WorksheetFunction.Match`.

```
Option Explicit
   Sub test()
Dim i As Integer, lastrow As Long, J As Long
Dim col1 As Range, col2 As Range, col3 As Range, col4 As Range, col5 As Range, col6 As Range
Dim c1arr, c2arr, c3arr, c4arr, c5arr, c6arr As Variant


Set col1 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("Reference", , xlValues, xlWhole)
Set col2 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("Amount", , xlValues, xlWhole)
Set col3 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("Action", , xlValues, xlWhole)
Set col4 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("Reference2", , xlValues, xlWhole)
Set col5 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("Amount2", , xlValues, xlWhole)
Set col6 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("Action2", , xlValues, xlWhole)

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, col1.Column).End(xlUp).Row

c1arr = Range(Cells(2, col1.Column), Cells(lastrow, col1.Column)).Value
c2arr = Range(Cells(2, col2.Column), Cells(lastrow, col2.Column)).Value
c3arr = Range(Cells(2, col3.Column), Cells(lastrow, col3.Column)).Value
c4arr = Range(Cells(2, col4.Column), Cells(lastrow, col4.Column)).Value
c5arr = Range(Cells(2, col5.Column), Cells(lastrow, col5.Column)).Value
c6arr = Range(Cells(2, col6.Column), Cells(lastrow, col6.Column)).Value

'Clear c6arr
ReDim c6arr(1 To UBound(c6arr, 1), 1 To 1)

For i = 1 To UBound(c1arr)
    If c2arr(i, 1) > 0 Then
        On Error Resume Next
            J = WorksheetFunction.Match(c1arr(i, 1), c4arr, 0)
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                If c2arr(i, 1) = c5arr(J, 1) Then
                    c6arr(J, 1) = c3arr(i, 1)
                Else
                    c6arr(J, 1) = "Manual Review"
                End If
            End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Next i

'Fill the blanks
For i = 1 To UBound(c6arr, 1)
    If c6arr(i, 1) = "" Then c6arr(i, 1) = "Manual Review"
Next i

Range(Cells(2, col6.Column), Cells(lastrow, col6.Column)).Value = c6arr
End Sub
```

These are the results using your most recently posted image:

[image]